# How to invert sphere collider/ spherical mesh in unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collider

I need to invert a spheres collider in unity and im not smart enough to be able to do it. if any of you help me it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

With the `SphereCollider` itself this is not possible.

But you could use a `MeshCollider` and assign a `Sphere` mesh to it.

Then you can invert all the normals by simply reversing all triangle indices like e.g.

```
// Linq provides handy shorthand queries and operations for IEnumerable collections
using System.Linq;

...

public MeshCollider meshCollider;

private void Awake ()
{
    if(!meshCollider) meshCollider = GetComponent<MeshCollider>();       

    var mesh = meshCollider.sharedMesh;

    // Reverse the triangles
    mesh.triangles = mesh.triangles.Reverse().ToArray();

    // also invert the normals
    mesh.normals = mesh.normals.Select(n => -n).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: when I tried that it gave me an error saying that meshCollider does not have a definintion of mesh in the line where you set var mesh

Comment: @ReidMonahan yeah typed that on the phone ^^ it should be [`sharedMesh`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MeshCollider-sharedMesh.html)