# How can I make a "collision in a collision"?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision, godot

How can I make a *"collision in a collision"* so that the fish swims inside the aquarium when it moves and does not fly away? If you just add the usual collision to the ball, the fish will simply be pushed out.

I tried to play with collisions, tried to make it as in the photo, but all to no avail [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjbHw.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to invert sphere collider/ spherical mesh in unity 3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69834564/how-to-invert-sphere-collider-spherical-mesh-in-unity-3d)

Comment: This didn't solve my problem. I need to do this in 2D, even though I didn't specify it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an edge collider and "draw" the aquarium collider. I assume it is rectangular so that shouldn't be a problem.
If it's a ball, you can either use assets from the asset store that handle it, or draw it yourself with the edge collider